# Bootstrap Modal Popup Multiple Images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have created a modal where on click of a link the modal pops up. Now there are multiple links at the footer which belong to multiple images. I want to open those images in the same pop up. Any Idea how?

[image: Attached is snapshot of what I want to do]

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what language you are using for the backend part of it but here is a solution using javascript/jquery/angular I'm sure you will be able to change it to your liking if it is what you want.

## index.html

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <a id="modal-456343" href="#modal-container-456343" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
        <div class="modal fade" id="modal-container-456343" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">

                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                            ×
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                            Modal title
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div style="width:100px; height:100px">
                        <img id="i" src="\images\fun.png" style="width:100%; height:100%">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="changeImage('img1')">
                            Image 1
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="changeImage('img2')">
                            Image 2
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                            Close
                        </button> 
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Save changes
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## javascript.js

```
$scope.imgUrls = {
    img1: "/images/yeoman.png",
    img2: "/images/fun.png"
}

$scope.changeImage = function(img){
    if(img == "img1") $("#i").attr('src', $scope.imgUrls.img1);
    if(img == "img2") $("#i").attr('src', $scope.imgUrls.img2);
}
```

This example lets you click on two buttons (they can be changed to anything element you want then add an onclick (mine is ng-click because of angular) to click them and then it changes the images accordingly.